# Добавить в имя переменной переменную которая увеличивается на один

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qpushbutton, qgroupbox

```py
def clicked(self): 
    self.f += 1 
    name_{f} = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
```

я хочу чтобы имя переменной было как показано каждый раз при нажатии `name_1`, `name_2`, `name_3`, `...`, но как это сделать?

Выдаёт ошибку. Смотрел на других сайтах, но там не очень понятно, есть какой-то модуль?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста всегда приводите минимально-воспроизводимый пример.

Вы не очень понятно объясняете что вы хотите сделать и
для чего вам это надо. Вместо этого вы спрашиваете
почему, то что вы написал не работает.

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите создать метод, который будет динамически создавать кнопки и
добавлять в `QGroupBox`. Если это так, то вот возможного варианта решения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self)                       
        groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(
            "border: 2px solid #D83A56; "
            "border-radius: 10;"
            "background-color: #ccffbd77;"
        )
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Add Button')
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: #77ff77; font-size: 30px;")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.my_clicked)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(groupBox_2)
        self.layout.addStretch(stretch=1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
  
        layout_main = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout_main.addWidget(QLabel('<h1>Hello World.</h1>', 
            alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop), 0)
        layout_main.addWidget(groupBox_2, 1)

        self.num = 1

    def my_clicked(self): 
        btn = QPushButton(f'Button {self.num}')
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #7777ff; font-size: 25px;")
        index = self.layout.count() - 2
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=btn :self.my_clicked_btn(btn))#
        self.layout.insertWidget(
            index, btn, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.num += 1 

    def my_clicked_btn(self, btn): 
        print(f'Вы нажали кнопку: {btn.text()}') #
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.resize(760, 650)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше не плодите переменные, а используйте список:

```
name = []
...
name.append(QPushButton(self.groupBox_2))
```

Или словарь:

```
name = {}
...
name[f] = QPushButton(self.groupBox_2)
```